# Undifferencing Time Series

Tags: time-series

How does one invert the differencing after the forecast has been made to get back to a forecast including the trend and seasonality that was differenced out? 
Currently, data is differenced only once.

Answer (score 2):

The difference operator for a time-series is defined by $\Delta X_t = X_t - X_{t-1}$.  Now, suppose you want to express some unobserved value $X_{t+k}$ back in terms of your last observed value $x_{t}$.  Inverting the differencing operation, you get:

$$X_{t+k} = x_{t} + \sum_{i=1}^{k} \Delta X_{t+i}.$$

Now, I am going to assume that you have observed data up to $x_t$ and you also have forecasts of the differenced variable after this.  In that case, you can obtain a (point) forecast of $X_t$ as:

$$\hat{X}_t = x_{t-k} + \sum_{i=0}^{k-1} \widehat{\Delta X}_i.$$

This would give you a forecast that is a point value; if you want an interval forecast you will need to aggregate the variance in your forecast variance for the individual differences.